# CSS Vs. font icons Vs. image in term of small icon

Tags: css, html

I've tried these 3 approaches out, and they all seem to give me the same result.
I tried to research to find out the different performance between them, I didn't come across anything so far.

[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-3"><span class="success-icon"> </span>icon</div>

<div class="col-lg-3"><i class="icon-circle-blank success"></i></span>icon</div>

<div class="col-lg-3"><img src="img/success-icon.png"></span>icon</div>
```

I'm wondering which way is the most efficient way to do and why ?

Comment: Obviously CSS & Font-awesome (which are the same) because you don't have to download the image. Plus if you're using a raster image it won't be scalable like the first two.

Comment: So with your conclusion, the first 2 will have the same efficiency, and the third option is the worst one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a performance perspective, a sprite image set or font icon would be preferable to using a single image for an icon. Still, using too many custom fonts can create some performance issues if you use a lot of them and a sprite image set is not always easily applicable to every situation or design.

If using font icons, use something like [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) to compile a custom font icon library that only includes what you need so that the size of your font library is minimal.

If using sprite image sets, use tools like [Dan's Tools Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) to render your sprite images with different alignment and different spacing to make it work for your project.

Don't use single images for each icon.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help.